# How to translate date to week name

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Could you please tell me that, how can I translate/detecting the following date format 2016-04-**29** and get the week name in pure JavaScript or jQuery? i.e Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The day of the week:

```
var 
    d = new Date('2016-04-29'); // April 29, 2016,
    days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

days[d.getDay()]; // "Friday"
```

Comment: No, no ,no ,no. Just use the standard javascript Date class. No need for arrays or an extra library. See my answer: stackoverflow.com/a/50293232/760777

Answer (score 0):

If you are open for libraries, try [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
alert(moment().format("dddd"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```